# How to structure a many to many django model with unique key account-user combinations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a issue with how to structure my django model.

I have a User model and an Account model.

The User can be in multiple accounts. Each User should have a key for each Account.

I want to be able to get the key associated with the account and user combination.

User 1 is in Account A and B. If I query for Account A and User 1 I should get key1 and if I query for B and 1 I should get key2.

keys = {AccountA: key1, AccountB: key2}

I'm just confused on how I can store this data. I know I could serialize json and store as a Text Field. But I think that will be messy. I want to be able to regenerate the keys if needed. What is the

```
class User(models.Model):
    accounts= models.ManyToManyField(Account)
    keys = models.TextField()
```

OR

```
class User(models.Model):
    accounts= models.ManyToManyField(Account)
    keys = models.ManyToManyField(AnotherModel?)
```

Something else? Caveats: I cant use hstore or jsonfield. I'm on django 1.7

Comment: What is a key and how is it related to the data model?

Comment: The key is a uuid.

Comment: Yeah, but what is a purpose of the key? I mean how is it used. Is it a key that gives any permissions?

Comment: yeah it would give a user permissions for each account they are connected to.

Comment: The last question. Does each user-account combination has a key or one key is related to one account?

Comment: Each user-account combination is unique.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is related to database normalization. I would advice to read more on that topic. Now back to the concrete example.

If each user-account combination is unique I would set up a many-to-many through relation.

```
class User(models.Model):
    accounts= models.ManyToManyField(Account, 
                                     through='UserAccount',
                                     related_name='user_accounts',
    )

class UserAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    account = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    key = models.UUIDField()
```

After that you can get all keys simple by selecting all UserAccount instances which are related to the concrete user.